# Use function with arguments within .each()

Tags: jquery, each

I want to use single function for different lists changin the arguments.

Statement like this `$( ".animals li" ).each(color);` works.
However, as I try to pass parameters, even empty, does not work `$( ".animals li" ).each(color());`

In my case I want to get function, which changes the color of the odd elements (color different).
Any way?

```
<ul class="animals">
            <li>cat</li>
            <li>hamster</li>
            <li>dog</li>
            <li>racoon</li>
            <li>rat</li>
</ul>

<ul class="plant">
            <li>pine</li>
            <li>oak</li>
            <li>fir</li>
            <li>birch</li>
            <li>palm </li>
</ul>

$( document ).ready(function(){
      $( ".animals li" ).each(color(ind, el, "green"));
    $( ".plant li" ).each(color(ind, el, "red"));
    
    
  function color( index, element, text_color ) { 
        if( index % 2 != 0 ) { 
          $( this ).css( "color", text_color ); 
        }
      }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/sp4k2wat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass the parameters like that. You need to pass it like:

```
$( ".animals li" ).each((ind, el) => color(ind, el, "green"));
```

That will do it. However, you need to fix your color function to not use 'this':

```
function color( index, element, text_color ) { 
        if( index % 2 != 0 ) { 
          $( element ).css( "color", text_color ); 
        }
      }
```